# How to select Multiple values from multiple Asp.net DropDown Values using jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I want to display Multiple dropdown selected values in jQuery.I am able to achieve this using html dropdown selection.How to achieve for asp dropdown box.The same thing is working for html selection.

```
                                  <div class="col-md-4">
                                        <div class="form-group form-group-sm">
                                            <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">Project Approved By:</label>
                                            <div class="col-sm-8">
                                                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlApprovedby" CssClass="dropdownlist" class="country" runat="server">
                                                    <asp:ListItem>--Select Approver--</asp:ListItem>
                                                    <asp:ListItem>SHLCC</asp:ListItem>
                                                    <asp:ListItem>SLSWCC</asp:ListItem>
                                                    <asp:ListItem>DLSWCC</asp:ListItem>
                                                </asp:DropDownList>

                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                        <div class="form-group form-group-sm">
                                            <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">Reservation:</label>
                                            <div class="col-sm-8">
                                                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlreservation" CssClass="dropdownlist" class="country" runat="server">
                                                    <asp:ListItem>--Select Reservation--</asp:ListItem>
                                                    <asp:ListItem>General</asp:ListItem>
                                                    <asp:ListItem>SC/ST</asp:ListItem>
                                                    <asp:ListItem>Women</asp:ListItem>
                                                    <asp:ListItem>Physically Challenged</asp:ListItem>
                                                    <asp:ListItem>Minorities</asp:ListItem>
                                                    <asp:ListItem>OBC</asp:ListItem>
                                                </asp:DropDownList>

                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
```

and My jQuery is

```
var countries = [];


        $.each($(".country option:selected"), function () {
            countries.push($(this).val());


        });


    alert("You have selectetions are " + countries.join(", "));
```

**My working fiddle for html selection is** http://jsfiddle.net/induuu/wL2h9k1m/

Answer (score 0):

You need to use

```
     <div>
    <asp:Button ID="btnModal" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" Text="Click me to get value"  />
    </div>
    <asp:ListBox ID="ListBox1" runat="server" SelectionMode="Multiple" ClientIDMode="Static">
                 <asp:ListItem>--Select Approver--</asp:ListItem>
                 <asp:ListItem>SHLCC</asp:ListItem>
                 <asp:ListItem>SLSWCC</asp:ListItem>
                 <asp:ListItem>DLSWCC</asp:ListItem>
   </asp:ListBox>
```

and in jQuery

```
<script>
        $(function () {
            $('#btnModal').on('click', function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();

                var listBoxValues = $('#ListBox1').val();//return []
                console.log(listBoxValues);
            });
        });
    </script>
```

and for your information you can use [select2](http://select2.github.io/select2/) for mutiple select

Comment: I want to select from both the dropdown selected values

Comment: just use `ClientIDMode="Static"` in asp.net control and jquery `var selectedValue=$('#id').val()`  if mutiple it will return array and if single than a single value will be returned by val() function

Comment: I Want to display values from both dropdown selected values like i can select one value from first dropdown and second value from second dropdown list and display both values

Answer (score 0):

This is what is you wanted...toy have two class in dropdwon list ..remove one

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $('#Button1').on('click', function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var ddl1 = $('#ddlApprovedby').val();
                var ddl2 = $('#ddlreservation').val();
                alert("You have selected the country - " + ddl1 + '->' + ddl2);
            });
            $('#Button2').on('click', function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var countries = [];
                $.each($(".country option:selected"), function () {
                    countries.push($(this).val());
                });
                alert("You have selected the country - " + countries.join(", "));
            });

        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

        <div class="col-md-4">
                                        <div class="form-group form-group-sm">
                                            <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">Project Approved By:</label>
                                            <div class="col-sm-8">
                                                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlApprovedby"  class="country" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static">
                                                    <asp:ListItem>--Select Approver--</asp:ListItem>
                                                    <asp:ListItem>SHLCC</asp:ListItem>
                                                    <asp:ListItem>SLSWCC</asp:ListItem>
                                                    <asp:ListItem>DLSWCC</asp:ListItem>
                                                </asp:DropDownList>

                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                        <div class="form-group form-group-sm">
                                            <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">Reservation:</label>
                                            <div class="col-sm-8">
                                                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlreservation"  class="country" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static">
                                                    <asp:ListItem>--Select Reservation--</asp:ListItem>
                                                    <asp:ListItem>General</asp:ListItem>
                                                    <asp:ListItem>SC/ST</asp:ListItem>
                                                    <asp:ListItem>Women</asp:ListItem>
                                                    <asp:ListItem>Physically Challenged</asp:ListItem>
                                                    <asp:ListItem>Minorities</asp:ListItem>
                                                    <asp:ListItem>OBC</asp:ListItem>
                                                </asp:DropDownList>

                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>


    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" ClientIDMode="Static" />
    <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Button2" ClientIDMode="Static" />

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry I Don't want to append values.Because some times i can select both or ore at a time.So i want to display only selected one.Can u please refer my fiddle in above the same i want for asp dropdown.

Comment: I want to use single button click.

Comment: Because i have so my dropdowns so that i cant use multiple buttons.

Comment: Ok.But i want to remove first list item in dropdown.i.e if i dont select any values from from dropdown i dont want to display anything.in this case if i dont select it will display '--Select Approver--',--Select Reservation--.

Comment: How to exclude this values?